# How to use OAuth2 in google-api-java-client?

Tags: oauth, google-api, google-api-java-client

I am trying to use the `PredictionSample` in `google-api-java-client`, but with `ClientLogin` authentication it gives me error:
`User is not a trusted tester`

I have activated the Google Prediction API in my APIs Console project. And I am able to run the Hello World prediction example from http://code.google.com/apis/predict/docs/hello_world.html with the same user. It uses oacurl and oauth2.

But it does not work with `google-api-java-client`. I am also not able to make oauth2 work with `google-api-java-client`.

I have searched the documentation and samples and have found no solution. Is it possible to do what is done in the hello_world example using the `google-api-java-client`.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem using Blogger API in my Google APP Engine Project. Attached is the link to the Stackoverflow question and sample code I was able to get working. Hope it helps.

[Proper Form of API request to Blogger using Java/App Engine -error 401](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20462705/proper-form-of-api-request-to-blogger-using-java-app-engine-error-401)